# OpenJPA: A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

I am getting above exception when trying to do a simple example using openjpa. Here I am using a custom persistance provider class. Following is my persistence.xml file. I went through the previous similar threads but couldn't find a proper solution with my configurations.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
             version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="juddiDatabase" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.juddi.test.persistance.JUDDIPersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
        <!-- entity classes -->
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.Address</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.AddressLine</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.AuthToken</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.BindingCategoryBag</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.BindingDescr</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.BindingTemplate</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.BusinessCategoryBag</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.BusinessDescr</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.BusinessEntity</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.BusinessIdentifier</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.BusinessName</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.BusinessService</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.CategoryBag</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.Clerk</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.ClientSubscriptionInfo</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.Contact</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.ContactDescr</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.DiscoveryUrl</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.Email</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.InstanceDetailsDescr</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.InstanceDetailsDocDescr</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.KeyedReference</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.KeyedReferenceGroup</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.Node</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.OverviewDoc</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.OverviewDocDescr</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.PersonName</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.Phone</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.Publisher</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.PublisherAssertion</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.PublisherAssertionId</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.ServiceCategoryBag</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.ServiceDescr</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.ServiceName</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.ServiceProjection</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.ServiceProjectionId</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.Subscription</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.SubscriptionChunkToken</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.SubscriptionMatch</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.Tmodel</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.TmodelCategoryBag</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.TmodelDescr</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.TmodelIdentifier</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.TmodelInstanceInfo</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.TmodelInstanceInfoDescr</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.TransferToken</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.TransferTokenKey</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.UddiEntity</class>
        <class>org.apache.juddi.model.UddiEntityPublisher</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="buildSchema(ForeignKeys=true)"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=ERROR, Tool=ERROR"/>
            <property name="openjpa.jdbc.UpdateManager" value="operation-order"/>
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="warn"/>

            <!-- h2 connection properties -->
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:h2:repository/database/juddiv3"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="test"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value="test"/>

            <!--  mysql connection properties
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/juddi"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionUserName" value="juddiv3"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionPassword" value=""/>
            -->
            <property name="openjpa.Compatibility" value="CheckDatabaseForCascadePersistToDetachedEntity=true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And I am getting the following error

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: A JDBC Driver or DataSource class name must be specified in the ConnectionDriverName property. Available properties in configuration are "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl@442ce698".
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.schema.DataSourceFactory.newDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:72)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.createConnectionFactory(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:844)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl.getDBDictionaryInstance(JDBCConfigurationImpl.java:602)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.endConfiguration(MappingRepository.java:1510)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:518)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.Configurations.configureInstance(Configurations.java:443)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.PluginValue.instantiate(PluginValue.java:104)
at org.apache.openjpa.conf.MetaDataRepositoryValue.instantiate(MetaDataRepositoryValue.java:68)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.conf.ObjectValue.instantiate(ObjectValue.java:83)
at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.newMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:968)
at org.apache.openjpa.conf.OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.getMetaDataRepositoryInstance(OpenJPAConfigurationImpl.java:959)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.makeReadOnly(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:638)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:203)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:227)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:154)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:60)
at org.apache.juddi.config.PersistenceManager.getEntityManager(PersistenceManager.java:45)
at org.apache.juddi.config.AppConfig.getPersistentConfiguration(AppConfig.java:109)
at org.apache.juddi.config.AppConfig.loadConfiguration(AppConfig.java:95)
at org.apache.juddi.config.AppConfig.<init>(AppConfig.java:62)
at org.apache.juddi.config.AppConfig.getInstance(AppConfig.java:183)
at org.apache.juddi.config.AppConfig.getConfiguration(AppConfig.java:205)
at org.apache.juddi.Registry.start(Registry.java:55)
```

Comment: Please, please, please do set openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses=warn. That property was disabled for a very good reason and you WILL encounter known bugs. I'd advise getting the -javaagent or buildtime enhancer setup.

Comment: Also, are there additional chained causes that you didn't show?

Comment: No..all is mentioned..where to put openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses =warn ? What is the use of it. Will it resolve my issue? Also didn't get what did you mean by "I'd advise getting the -javaagent or buildtime enhancer setup"

Comment: BTW I am running OSGi env. And also please find the persistence.xml file that I have provided with the link where I have already defined the property openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses=warn.

Comment: Sorry, do NOT set that property...

Comment: Thanks Rick for the response.I removed that property and still same result. FYI just before the above error log I am also getting the following warning.


20  WARN   [Framework Event Dispatcher] openjpa.Runtime - The configuration property named "openjpa.Id" was not recognized and will be ignored, although the name closely matches a valid property called "openjpa.Id".

Comment: Any idea what I am missing ?  Do you have any links/example on how to add a custom persistence provider along with its persistence.xml? I also tried with using the very same org.apache.openjpa.PersistenceProviderImpl class but just changed the name as forementioned. Still having this issue. So it is not something  about the provider class. But something else

Comment: At this point I'm not sure, I'd grab the source and start looking around.

Comment: Thanks, will wait for your reply. FYI I am using openjpa 2.2.0 version.

Comment: No, I was suggesting that you dig into the code. I'm already up to my eyeballs in work.

Comment: How is your persistence.xml deployed? What is your file structure?

Answer (score 1):

in your `persistence.xml` config file you have several datasource descriptions (MySQL and H2). Delete one of them and try again.

Comment: The MySQL connection properties are commented out <!-- ... -->

Comment: Yes that it commented out.